# ValueError: A target array with shape (72148, 23) was passed for an output of shape (None, 826, 23) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a 1D CNN on heartbeat data to classify pathological heartbeats. Input and output shapes are

```
X_train = np.zeros((72148, 828, 1))
y_train = np.zeros((72148, 23))
```

However, fitting the model using those shapes results in an error that especially confuses me because of the "for an output of shape (None, 826, 23)". Any suggestions as to why this occurs would be highly appreciated!
Full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/1SchoolProjects/2019-2020/Term4/NN/NNHeartbeats/CNN_heatbeats.py", line 81, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size= batch_size)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\tensorflow-gpu-cuda10\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\tensorflow-gpu-cuda10\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 235, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\tensorflow-gpu-cuda10\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 593, in _process_training_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\tensorflow-gpu-cuda10\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 646, in _process_inputs
    x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\tensorflow-gpu-cuda10\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2383, in _standardize_user_data
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\tensorflow-gpu-cuda10\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2489, in _standardize_tensors
    y, self._feed_loss_fns, feed_output_shapes)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\tensorflow-gpu-cuda10\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 810, in check_loss_and_target_compatibility
    ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '
ValueError: A target array with shape (72148, 23) was passed for an output of shape (None, 826, 23) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

model summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 826, 512)          2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 826, 256)          131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 826, 256)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 826, 23)           5911      
=================================================================
Total params: 139,287
Trainable params: 139,287
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def create_model(n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs):
    tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float16')
    dtype='float16'

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), kernel_size=3, filters=512),
        #tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_shape=(828,1), units=828, activation='relu', dtype=dtype),
        #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, dtype=dtype),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', dtype=dtype),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, dtype=dtype),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax', dtype=dtype)
    ])

    return model



if __name__ == "__main__":
    X_train = np.zeros((72148, 828, 1))
    y_train = np.zeros((72148, 23))
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], y_train.shape[1]
    model = create_model(n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs)
    #optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    #loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    #model.compile(loss=loss_fn, optimizer=optimizer)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(model.summary())



    batch_size = 32

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size= batch_size)
```

Comment: you have to reduce the dimensionality inside your network... you have to pass from 3d to 2d in order to match your target. you can do this with globalpooling or flatten layer. if u are interested I can provide u some examples

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Thanks for the quick answer! I've seen flatten layers before but I would not know at which point in the network I would have to insert one. Can you explain that to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are some examples to pass from 3d to 2d

with Flatten... you can put it in your network before the output layer

```
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = 826, 1, 23
n_samples = 1000

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,n_outputs, n_samples)).values

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), kernel_size=3, filters=16),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')

model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

with GlobalPooling layers which compress the temporal dimension

```
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = 826, 1, 23
n_samples = 1000

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,n_outputs, n_samples)).values

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), kernel_size=3, filters=16),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(), # also GlobalMaxPooling1D() is ok
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')

model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How again one short line of code can change everything..